# C#: How do you keep selected Items highlighted in a ListBox on a WindowsForm application?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a `ListBox` where I select some `Item`(s) in it which get highlighted. Then I press a `Button` to move the `Item` up. After I click that 'up' `Button` and it does what it's supposed to, that same `Item` isn't highlighted anymore - which I still want it to be.
How come?

I looked up the properties for `ListBox` and didn't see anything that would match this situation. However, I did see a `ListView` property called `HideSelection` that seems to be what I'm looking for, but my `Control` isn't a `ListView`, it's a `ListBox`.

Basically the question is:
How do I keep those `Item`s highlighted after I click the `Button`?
I'm a little lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Then I press a Button to move the Item up.---how? this is not built in behaviour

Comment: Created a button and made a click event on that 'up' button

Comment: Put that code because that is the key. you may need add `Focus()`

Comment: Simply set HideSelection to false!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I didn't understand wrong you are looking for `SetSelected()` method.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                int selectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
                object selectedItem = listBox1.SelectedItem;
                listBox1.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
                listBox1.Items.Insert(selectedIndex - 1, selectedItem);
                listBox1.SetSelected(selectedIndex -1, true); // here we go
            }
        }
```

**Result;**

[image]

Hope helps,

Comment: That looks like what I'm trying to do. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that @Nick